# Pymongo Updating Record by ObjectId

Tags: flask, pymongo, objectid

I am getting the following when I try to use the _id in MongoDB to then update a record:

id: "{'$oid': '643c1049138324bd119ab59b'}"

I want to get the 643c1049138324bd119ab59b part separated from the full expression so I can send it to my API.

In fact, I want to be able to pass a variable with the correct ObjectId, not just hard coding the ObjectId

It looks like this so far. But when I pass the id to the "query":id to then get to the api, nothing updates.

```
@app.route('/update/<id>/<blogtitle>/<blogpost>', methods=['GET','POST'])  
def update(id, blogtitle, blogpost):  
    try:  
        if request.method == 'GET':  
            return render_template('update.html', title='Update Record', blogtitle=blogtitle, old_post=blogpost)  
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            blogpost = request.form['blogpost']    
            url = 'http://localhost:7071/api/UpdateRecord'  
            x=requests.post(url, params={"query":id,"new_data":blogpost})
            print("response text", x.text)
            print("response code", x.status_code)
            return redirect(url_for('viewrecords'))
        return render_template("update.html", blogtitle=id)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

This attempt does not work:

```
@app.route('/update/<id>/<blogtitle>/<blogpost>', methods=['GET','POST'])  
def update(id, blogtitle, blogpost):  
    try:  
        if request.method == 'GET':  
            return render_template('update.html', title='Update Record', blogtitle=blogtitle, old_post=blogpost)  
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            blogpost = request.form['blogpost'] 
            new_id=ObjectId(id)   
            url = 'http://localhost:7071/api/UpdateRecord'  
            x=requests.post(url, params={"query":new_id,"new_data":blogpost})
```

when I test a hardcoded version, it does work.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #creates the code to update the info when the submit button is pressed
        blogpost = request.form['blogpost']
        fake_id=ObjectId('643c1049138324bd119ab59b')
        url = 'http://localhost:7071/api/UpdateRecord'
        x=requests.post(url, params={"query":fake_id,"new_data":blogpost})
```

Any ideas what I can do to get all this to talk to one another nicely. Thanks.

**For clarity, I would like to be able to get the 643c1049138324bd119ab59b
from "{'$oid': '643c1049138324bd119ab59b'}"
for any record in a MongoDB database.**

OTHER PARTS OF THE CODE:

For the Azure function API:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import data_manager

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed an update request.')

    query_string = req.params.get('query') #MongoDB _id
    new_data_string = req.params.get('new_data') #the updated blogpost

    data_manager.initialize()
    updated_record=data_manager.update({'_id':query_string}, {'blogpost': new_data_string})
    if updated_record:
        return func.HttpResponse(status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(status_code=500)
```

In the data_manager.py file

```
def update(query, new_values):
    global mycol
    try:
        mycol.update_many(query, {'$set': new_values})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

and the html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="section">     
        <h1>Update Your Message</h1>
        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Index</a> > Update Record
        <p>
        <h1>Original Title: {{ blogtitle }}</h1>
        <!--Creates a form to update the blogpost, prefills the form with the old info-->
        <form method="post">         
            <label for="Message">Blog Post:</label>
            <br>
            <textarea name="blogpost",
            maxlength="1000",
            rows="5",
            cols="80",value="{{ request.form['blogpost'] }}">{{ old_post }}</textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pymongo you can get the ObjectId value using the `str()` built-in.

```
id_str = str(obj_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not change the id variable. In debugger, both are: {'$oid': '643c1049138324bd119ab59b'}

Comment: '$oid' is just a representation of on ObjectId in strict JSON format. We would need to see the code where you are performing the update operation to be able to help more. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId

Comment: Thank you. I updated the original post with the relevant additional code.

Comment: I can't really tell what is going on but as a guess when you are passing the ObjectId to requests / flask, it is converting it to canonical JSON as per the link above. Checkout the `loads()` method in the json_util library https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html

Answer (score 0):

This sample code shows how a `$oid` is created from an `ObjectId` using `dumps()` and how you can use `loads()` to convert it back into an `ObjectId` again.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId
from bson.json_util import loads, dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

my_id = ObjectId('5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a490')
my_str = dumps(my_id)
print(my_str)
my_record = {'field': loads(my_str)}
db.mycollection.insert_one(my_record)
print(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

prints:

```
{"$oid": "5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a490"}
{'_id': ObjectId('644abccf5e243bde20a8b82e'), 'field': ObjectId('5c7fec06d2ea12b0cdc7a490')}
```